# Should I be normalizing an invoice database tableset?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am building an online invoicing platform but am struggling with the concept of normalization as it relates to the line items placed on every invoice. My table structures are as follows:

### employers

- ID (PK, autoincrement)
- empID (int)
- name (varchar)
- (other irrelevant fields)

### member

- ID (PK, autoincrement)
- empID (FK to employers)
- memberid (int)
- name (varchar)
- (other irrelevant fields)

### plans

- planid (PK, autoincrement)
- description (varchar)
- price (decimal)

### member_plans

- ID (PK, autoincrement)
- memberid (FK to member)
- planid (FK to plans, int)
- status (int, 1 for active, 0 for inactive)
- start (datetime)
- end (datetime, can be null)

### invoices

- invoiceid (PK, autoincrement)
- empID (FK to employers)
- date (datetime)
- subtotal (decimal)
- vat (decimal)
- previous_owed (decimal)
- status (int)

### invoice_items

- ID (PK, autoincrement)
- invoiceid (FK to invoices)
- memberid (FK to members)
- planid (FK to plans)
- price (decimal)

Member belong to employer groups. Employers pay the dues on behalf of their members. Each member can select multiple plans so the invoice will have line items (memberid, name) along with subitems for each member (planid, description, price). The sum of all plans by each member is grouped together and invoiced to the employer for online review.

I want to, at any time, be able to go back and generate an invoice based on the date selected. Currently, I would be importing, essentially, a snapshot of all existing member_plans each month, importing into invoice_items and assigning a invoiceid. This seems like a lot of data being replicated (though it may be necessary for a true snapshot because the start and end dates in member_plans is not truly indicative of certain factors, i.e. the end date can be changed at any point in time "as if" the member was never active during a certain time period when they were - due to chargebacks or legal issues).

Are there proper/efficient ways to normalize the invoice_items table or is the method I have listed really the only proper way to do this? The plan is to archive invoices after 7 months anyway so while table size is of concern, it is not a never ending-growth table.

Comment: What s the difference between ID and empId (ie can you have 3 empIDs the same

Comment: This already looks normalized.  Where do you think the data duplication is occurring?  Note that ID's don't count as duplication.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - it seems the duplication is this: if I am member 1 and I have 5 plans, each month, those 5 plans are insert into the invoice_items table. Theoretically, nothing about those 5 plans changed during the course of time but are just snapshots of my "member_plans" each month for reference. So each month, member id 1 with planid 1,2,3,4,5 and prices, 1,2,3,4,5 respectively show up with only a different invoiceid in the invoice_items table

Comment: @Mark - I was always taught to have an autoincementing PK in tables - I very rarely, if ever would use it. It and empID are both unique. empID is not autoincrementing (created differently)

Comment: @JM4  I wouldn't consider the line items as duplicates, IMO from a DB standpoint.  They are the same items, but they are appearing as instances in different billed invoices, so for the purposes of recording, they are not independent entities that appear in duplicate.  I would consider you data structure normalized.

Comment: Is it really even worth using subtotal in the invoices table since this can be calculated from the prices in the items list? Also - plan was to insert items into table but since invoiceid is created as autoincremented ID, perhaps I have things backwards.

Comment: If somebody wants to throw down an answer and perhaps can provide advice on my last comment, I'll accept as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few small design issues with invoice_items.

```
ID (PK, autoincrement)
invoiceid (FK to invoices)
memberid (FK to members)
planid (FK to plans)
price (decimal)
```

ID is unnecessary, and without any other changes, is a broken surrogate key. It's broken, because as a surrogate it's supposed to take the place of a natural key, but you haven't created a natural key.  (The word *surrogate* essentially means "takes the place of". For example, a *surrogate* mother takes the place of a natural birth mother.)

Let's look at some pseudo-SQL.

```
create table invoice_items (
  invoiceid integer not null,

  -- Traditionally, line items are numbered sequentially starting at 1
  -- for each invoice. Your traditions might be different. "Some sane value"
  -- prevents you from sending someone a 10,000 line invoice by mistake.
  -- See below (way below) for implementing CHECK() constraints in MySQL.
  -- A constraint that says, "Start with 1, no gaps" would be nice. I'll
  -- let you code that one. ;)
  line_item_num integer not null check (line_item_num >= 1 and
                                        line_item_num <= [some sane value]),

  memberid integer not null,
  planid integer not null,

  -- Choose the range to fit your application, and to prevent egregious mistakes.
  price decimal(...) not null check (price between -10000 and 10000),

  -- This constraint implements the traditional idea of invoice line items.
  primary key (invoiceid, line_item_num),

  -- This constraint prevents billing a single member plan twice on one invoice.
  -- It might need to be dropped. For example, if you invoice one line item for
  -- the base price for a member plan, then also invoice one line item for 
  -- a discount to the same member plan, you'd need to drop this constraint.
  unique (invoiceid, memberid, planid),

  foreign key (invoiceid) references invoices (invoiceid),

  -- This foreign key needs to reference the single table member_plans, not the 
  -- two tables members and plans. Referencing the single table prevents you from
  -- invoicing a member for a plan that member hasn't chosen.
  foreign key (memberid, planid) references member_plans (memberid, planid)
);
```

You mentioned "description" as part of this table, but left it out of your list of columns. I left it out, too.

**Check constraints in MySQL**

MySQL doesn't support CHECK() constraints. In some cases, it's practical to implement a CHECK() constraint as a foreign key reference to another table. For example, it's practical to implement the CHECK() constraint I wrote for line_item_num above as a foreign key reference to a table of line item numbers.

In other cases, a foreign key reference might not be practical. For example, price might have too great a range for you to implement this way. A range of -10000.00 to +10000.00 takes a couple of million rows.  One alternative is to use a trigger. In the worst case, you might have to rely on application code and an exception report. (An exception report runs occasionally to search for invalid values that have slipped through the cracks.)

**Some other things to look at . . .**

Invoice id numbers *usually* aren't autoincrementing integers. Autoincrementing integers can have gaps. Accountants *hate* gaps. Sooner or later, they'll want to know what happened to invoice number 10156, and they do *not* like hearing "that's probably just a number that the dbms dropped because of a failed transaction or something."

If employers.empID is unique, adding another column with an id number doesn't make it more unique. Same is true for members.memberid. See [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).